# how to json_encode an object of several array of objcts in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, object

i want to produce a json like below:

```
{
    "success":[{
        "success": "1"
    }],
    "friends": [
        {
            "name": "ali",
            "phone": "934453"
        },
        {
            "name": "reza",
            "phone": "934453"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is my code after a query from a mysql table:

```
$i=0
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $friend[$i] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'phone' => $row['phone']);
    $i++;
}
$success = 1;
$result = array('success' => $success , 'friends' => $friend);
echo json_encode($result);
```

but it doesn't work fine.

surprisingly this is what i get in the result after trying your suggestions! :

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: requestid in E:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php on line <i>149</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0011</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>152808</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1.0119</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>189880</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Functions->doIhaveNewFriends(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>134</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: data in E:\wamp\www\android_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php on line <i>169</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0011</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>152808</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1.0119</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>189880</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Functions->doIhaveNewFriends(  )</td><td title='E:\wamp\www\android_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>134</td></tr>
</table></font>
null
```

Comment: It should work fine from the code you've posted. Is your database query failing? Have you done any error checking to make sure it is bringing back the data you expect? Have you initialized the $friend array as a blank array before you try and use it?

Comment: it doesn't work means? tell what error or problem are you getting? whereas you have not add `;` at the end of `$i=0`

Comment: i'm getting html code instead of json. help please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $friend = new stdClass;
    $friend->name = $row['name'];
    $friend->phone = $row['phone'];
    $friends[] = $friend;
}
$success = array('success'=>1);
$result = array('success' => $success , 'friends' => $friends);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: There is no fundamental difference here between this answer and the original. The problem is not with how he's adding the values to the JSON output.

Comment: your solutions were right. mistake was mine in some other place of my code. thanks a lot.
and i actually used your previous code.